# iOS Developer Program Company Distribution

Tags: ios, xcode, certificate

So I am very new to xcode and iOS and just getting use to everything. I have successfully understood how Developer Certificates work but I am stumped on Distribution Certificates. Since each member of the company is using the same Distribution Certificates who should the Private Key be assigned to? Sorry if this makes no sense, but I'm having a hard to grasping how to use this. I successfully created a Dist Cert for myself (admin role) and it works and I can create the .ipa file that I upload to TestFlight but how will others in my team use this Cert? Will I need to give them my private key?

Comment: Not an answer, but a reflection on how it's handled where I work. In my company, we have one team lead who creates the final build which is used in production. Several members of the team can modify projects and commit changes to our repository, but when it's time to push an app in to production our team lead check the final code out of the repository and uses his private key.

Comment: Thanks, I guess I was worried for no reason. You only need one person compiling the code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Private key should be in the keychain of the developer that compiles the application. After compiling and packaging, he can distribute the binary and the provisioning profile to other people in the company.

This is the way both AdHoc and Enterprise distribution work.

If you need to, you can export the private key as a p12 file from the keychain of the developer who created it and install it in other machines. This way, more than one developer can create and distribute binaries.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't really matter who the private key is assigned to in theory.  In practice you would want it as one of the more responsible people in your company (you as the admin role of the account, it makes sense).

Everyone who is compiling a version of the app for distribution will need to use that certificate, and will need a copy of your private key.  It is not absolutely necessary for everyone to have a copy of the private key, as you can just have one centralized location for building the distribution package, and that machine will have the private key installed on it